# Getting all videos duration using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For mp4 file, windows shows its duration as follows:

[image]

I want to know duration of all videos in the subdirectories in some directory and with names starting with "13."

I tried somethingl like this:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir(/vid/dir')
for file in glob.glob("**/*.mp4"):
    if file.startswith("13."):
        print(file)
        print(os.stat(file))
```

and it printed something like this:

```
vid1
os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=281474976711102, st_dev=3060572141, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=4790865, st_atime=1607201443, st_mtime=1588698486, st_ctime=1595071282)
vid2
os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=281474976711110, st_dev=3060572141, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=35642204, st_atime=1595071282, st_mtime=1588704289, st_ctime=1595071282)
vid3
os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=281474976711118, st_dev=3060572141, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=8671663, st_atime=1607191378, st_mtime=1588698521, st_ctime=1595071282)
```

But I did not find video length in these attributes. How do I obtain video length? Can it be done without win32api or some video library?

Comment: have you tried/can you use cv2

Comment: no, I havent tried cv2

Comment: I feel if windows provides this as file attribute then it should be fairly easy to obtain without using any speacilized videos specific library

Comment: correct but I believe windows just stores those values after reading the video, what your seeing is metadata

Answer (score -1):

Here is the open cv2 solution

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
duration = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
```